# Type for Cinemachine in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a freelook camera, and I want it so that it only turns when the player drags the right mouse button. The problem is, since Cinemachine is a plugin, I'm not sure what type I should set the FreeLook Camera component. I want to make something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine.Utility;

public class lookOnDrag : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Not sure what type to set CFL
    private Cinemachine CFL;

    void Start()
    {
        CFL = GetComponent<CinemachineFreeLook>();
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            CFL.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CFL.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked the documentation thoroughly and don't have an answer.

Comment: Well. The obvious is you are looking for a type of CinemachineFreeLook … so. You have your type

Comment: @BugFinder sarcastic comments are not helpful. Isaac, have you taken a look at the BindingMode property?

Comment: @ErikOverflow actually not sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably entered the above reference incorrectly and it does not recognize it correctly. using only `Cinemachine` and delete <del>`utility`</del>.

```cs
using Cinemachine;
```

Also define the variable according to the component or `CinemachineVirtualCameraBase`;

```cs
private CinemachineFreeLook CFL;

void Start()
{
    CFL = GetComponent<CinemachineFreeLook>();
}
```